# Cannot run Stardew Valley with PlayOnLinux

Tags: graphics, playonlinux

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and I just bought Stardew Valley via GOG and used the installer with PlayOnLinux to install it. It said the install went perfectly. I ran it and got this error:

```
No suitable graphics card found.
Could not find a Direct3D device that supports the XNA Framework HiDef profile.
Verify that a suitable graphics device is installed.
Make sure that the desktop is not locked, and that no other application is running in full screen mode.
Avoid running under Remote Desktop or as a Windows Service.
```

I've got Intel Integrated Graphics 3000. I've tried [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/296470/discussions/0/34093781740855384/) solution, but still got the same error. What do I do?

If it just isn't possible to run it on Linux, could you direct me to a thread to install Windows alongside Ubuntu (ubuntu installed first).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The [Wine App DB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33441) is always a good resource for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could wait for it to get ported. According to this [Gaming on Linux article](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/stardew-valley-developer-says-linux-is-a-top-priority-woohoo.6855?utm_content=buffer10244&utm_medium=social&utm_source=plus.google.com&utm_campaign=buffer), OS X and Linux are top priorities now.

Comment: Like we've never seen a port for Linux to get abandoned before even with a lot of hype surrounding it...

Answer (score -1):

Try installing `dotnet40`, `xna40`, and `xact` from PlayOnlinux Install components

Comment: If it was that easy people would have probably already made the game work on Linux...

Answer (score -2):

You could do 2 things:

Wait for the game to get ported to linux
Or
Download the game for Windows and run it with wine. Install wine with the command "sudo apt-get install wine"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install and run this game with wine. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)